# Fitting multiple curves to one data set

Tags: linux, perl, plot, awk, gnuplot

I have a data set that I receive from an outside source, and have no real control over.

The data, when plotted, shows two clumps of points with several sparse, irrelevant points. Here is a sample plot:

[image]

There is a clump of points on the left, clustered around `(1, 16)`. This clump is actually part of a set of points that lies on (or near to) a line stretching from `(1, 17.5)` to `(2.4, 13)`.

There is also an apparent curve from `(1.75, 18)` to `(2.75, 12.5)`.

Finally, there are some sparse points above the second curve, around `(2.5, 17)`.

Visually, it's not difficult to separate these groups of points. However, I need to separate these points within the data file into three groups, which I'll call Line, Curve, and Other (the Curve group is the one I actually need). I'd like to write a program that can do this reasonably well without needing to visually see the plot.

Now, I'm going to add a couple items that make this much worse. This is only a sample set of data. While the shapes of the curve and line are relatively constant from one data set to the next, the positions are not. These regions can (and do) shift, both horizontally and vertically. The only real constant is that there's a negative-slope line from the top-left to the bottom-right of the plot, an almost [image: fourth-power inverse ration] curve from the top-center to the bottom-right, and most of the sparse points are in the top-right corner, above the curve.

I'm on Linux, and I'm out of ideas. I can tell you the approaches that I've tried, though they have not done well.

- First, I cleaned up the data set and sorted it in ascending order by x-coordinate. I thought that maybe the points were sorted in some sort of a logical way that would allow me to 'head' or 'tail' the data to achieve the desired result, but this was not the case.
- I can write a code in anything (Python, Fortran, C, etc.) that removes a point if it's not within X distance of the previous point. This would be just fine, except that the scattering of the points is such that two points very near each other in x, are separated by an appreciable distance in y. It also doesn't help that the Line and Curve draw near one another for larger x-values.
- I can fit a curve to a partial data set. When I sort the data by x-coordinate, for example, I can choose to only plot the first 30 points, or the last 200, or some set of 40 in the middle somewhere. That's not a problem. But the Line points tuck underneath the Curve points, which causes a problem.
- If the Line points were fairly constant (which they're not), I could rotate my plot by some angle so that the Line is vertical and I can just look at the points to the right of that line, then rotate back. This may the best way to go about doing this, but in order to do that, I need to be able to isolate the linear points, which is more or less the essence of the problem.

The other idea that seems plausible to me, is to try to identify point density and split the data into separate files by those parameters. I think this is the best candidate for this problem, since it is independent of point location. However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this, especially because the Line and Curve do come quite close together for larger x-values (In the sample plot, it's x-values greater than about 2).

I know this does not exactly fall in with the request of a MWE, but I don't know how I'd go about providing a more classical MWE. If there's something else I can provide that would help, please ask. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using all your data together?  then your analysis will account for shifts in x and y.  Just a suggestion. I sure don't know what will work.

Comment: The data doesn't all come in at once. It's an ongoing project. But I'm not sure that putting more data together will help; I think it would cause more overlap, thereby making the process more difficult. Also, each data set corresponds to a different instance, though the instances are similar enough to one another to be able to _hopefully_ be treated with a single algorithm.

Comment: ok. Makes sense.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @jww The problem is that I don't have any sort of code that does what I want it to do. I can provide things that accomplish small portions, but this isn't about code not doing what it's intended to do in the sense of malfunctioning, but rather about trying to find an idea that will address the problem.

Comment: Basic though to try is to partition the field then curve fit the partitions.
There are a bajillion ways to partition/cluster points in a field. 
I might first try K-means variant to partition. (edit) where k=3